# How to include a command line Gradle build script for a java program

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, command-line-tool, command-line-arguments

Say I have a java program HelloWord.java and it has no dependencies, just a simple program, how do I include a command line Gradle build script so someone can run the project?

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) can be used specifically for this.

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'foo.org.Main'
```